# Static page must be recent post page

Tags: wordpress, posts

I have a problem. 
I need to make a WordPress site.
And I want in the page "News" the recent posts.
But I have a Home page and it needs to look exactly like the News page.
But is it true that I can only make one recent posts page?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can have as many "recent posts" pages as you want.

You'll need to create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates), and use something like [WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [wp_get_recent_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) to query the database for the most recent posts.